# SQL Query to retrieve data based on latitude and longitude not working

Tags: sql, wordpress, geolocation

Folks, any idea why this query doesn't return any results?

I'm trying to get rows from the DB based on the distance between coordinates.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ID,
        p.post_title,
        map_lat.meta_value as locLat,
        map_lng.meta_value as locLong,
        ( 6371 * acos(
        cos( radians( '-25.427603111334' ) )
        * cos( radians( map_lat.meta_value ) )
        * cos( radians( map_lng.meta_value ) - radians( '' ) )
        + sin( radians( '-25.427603111334' ) )
        * sin( radians( map_lat.meta_value ) )
        ) )
        AS distance
 FROM wpby_posts p
        INNER JOIN wpby_postmeta map_lat ON p.ID = map_lat.post_id
        INNER JOIN wpby_postmeta map_lng ON p.ID = map_lng.post_id
        WHERE 1 = 1
        AND p.post_type = 'listar'
        AND map_lat.meta_key = 'latitude'
        AND map_lng.meta_key = 'longitude'
        HAVING distance < '1000'
        ORDER BY distance ASC
```

All I get is:

```
>>> Query OK, 0 rows affected
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Presumably because there are no records that match your filter/join conditions?

Comment: No. The records are there

Comment: Change your INNER JOINS to LEFT OUTER JOINS and remove you WHERE/HAVING clauses - your query should now return rows. Then add each element back one by one, re-running the query each time, until you find which element is filtering out your records

Comment: I figured out that was the part that calculates the distance that is not working. Without it I get all rows. Don't know how to fix that though. I am trying to find a way to do that calculation. that is the core of the query.

Comment: It would seem that you've cast the value of `map_lat.meta_value` as something else, but continue to refer to it as `map_lat.meta_value`